Using dpkg to install packages in a bash script
So there's a program I use regularly that doesn't auto-update, each time there's a new update I have to re-download the .deb file, and reinstall it through the command line. This is a basic task but I found it annoying so I decided to do a small challenge and write a script to do it for me. I've run into an issue though that I'm not sure how to resolve. Here's the relevant code:
wget -O $path$placeholderFile -q $URL

if diff $path$placeholderFile $path$finalFile;
then
    rm $path$placeholderFile
else
    mv $path$placeholderFile $path$finalFile
    dpkg -i $path$finalFile
fi

I expect this code to download the file to a placeholder, check if it's actually a new update or the same version, and then install it if it is actually a new update. However, the install doesn't seem to work. I know that I have to run this script as root in order for this to work, because dpkg only works with sudo privileges. And it does successfully overwrite the finalFile if it is a new update, but for some reason dpkg itself doesn't work as I expected it to.
Edit:
The general description of dpkg's misbehavior is that it doesn't seem to be running in this script at all. The script finishes running with no error messages, the new package has been downloaded and has overwritten the previous package, but it hasn't actually been installed.
As for the second comment, I guess what you're saying is I don't need an if statement at all, I can just simply run dpkg on the new file and dpkg will do the work for me. I didn't really think about that, but I still think the code I wrote should work. I'd like to understand why it doesn't work more than just solving the problem, if that makes sense.
I don't understand how permissions can be the problem here. I run it using sudo. Whenever I forget to add sudo, the script runs up til the end and then dpkg fails bc it doesn't have the required permissions. This is expected behavior.
Final edit:
The classic, I changed nothing but it works now for some reason. Here's the bash -x output, I intentionally installed an older version for testing of functionality
+ path=/home/sam/Downloads/
+ placeholderFile=placeholder.deb
+ finalFile=discord.deb
+ URL='https://discord.com/api/download?platform=linux&format=deb'
+ wget -O /home/sam/Downloads/placeholder.deb -q 'https://discord.com/api/download?platform=linux&format=deb'
+ diff /home/sam/Downloads/placeholder.deb /home/sam/Downloads/discord.deb
Binary files /home/sam/Downloads/placeholder.deb and /home/sam/Downloads/discord.deb differ
+ mv /home/sam/Downloads/placeholder.deb /home/sam/Downloads/discord.deb
+ dpkg -i /home/sam/Downloads/discord.deb
(Reading database ... 192118 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../home/sam/Downloads/discord.deb ...
Unpacking discord (0.0.68) over (0.0.25) ...
Setting up discord (0.0.68) ...
10096
10099
10100
10102
10145
10154
10158
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1) ...

The issue I was having previously is that it would run everything, but when I opened discord it would still prompt me to download and install the new update rather than just opening and running.

Do you have the relevant error messages from dpkg, or a general description of dpkg's misbehavior?

If you run dpkg -i package and (based on meta inside) the package is newer than installed it will update it.

Your underlying problem (permissions) will be solved by adding an entry to your sudoers file allowing your user to use that command without a password.  When you do it, you have the option here to allow your user to be able to install ALL packages this way.  choose carefully.

Please insert a line set -x in your script before your code or run the unchanged script as bash -x yourscript and show the resulting output. [Edit] your question, copy&paste the output and format it as a code block.
